# tikz-3dplot: How can I recover the x,y,z components of a previously defined coordinate?

Tags: coordinates, tikz-3dplot

Specifically, in order to use the `\tdplotsetcoord` command to define coordinates and then use the `\tdplotdefinepoints(Vx,Vy,Vz)(Ax,Ay,Az)(Bx,By,Bz)` command that requires the x,y,z components of the three points to be known prior to calling the `\tdplotdrawpolytopearc` command to draw an arc between two vectors.

Can anyone help me fix my approach or demonstrate another method that works?

```
% drawing the axes
\draw[very thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (8,0,0) node[anchor=north east, very thick]{$y$ (West)};
\draw[very thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,8,0) node[anchor=north west, very thick]{$x$ (South)};
\draw[very thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,8) node[anchor=south, very thick]{$z$ (Zenith)};

% defining the origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

% ploting sun vector and angles
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{8}{40}{60}
% draw a vector from origin to point (P)
\draw[-stealth,thick,color=red] (O) -- (P);

% plotting vector of the sky element
\tdplotsetcoord{Q}{8}{40}{-15}
% draw a vector from origin to point (Q)
\draw[-stealth,thick,color=blue] (O) -- (Q) node[thick,above] {se};

% plotting vector of the collector normal
\tdplotsetcoord{R}{8}{46}{115}
% draw a vector from origin to point (R)
\draw[-stealth,thick,color=nrkgreen] (O) -- (R) node[thick,above] {cn};

\tdplotdefinepoints(O)(P)(R) % problem in code is here!!!
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[<->]{2}{anchor=north west}{$\theta$}
```